# String formatting options

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, xtend, bitwise-and

I am porting a C code to xtend, and I have an 32bit integer. Since Java's Integer has a maximum value of `0x7FFFFFFF`, I decided to use Long because I would need `0xFFFFFFFF`.

When I print it out,

```
Long value = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
String::Format("0x%08X", value);
```

I am getting the `output: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. I am expecting to only get `0xFFFFFFFF`.
To get rid of the leading Fs, I tried doing this:

```
value.bitwiseAnd(0x00000000FFFFFFFF)
```

But the output is still the same. How can I format it in `String::Format` such that it will not display the the first `FFFFFFFF`? I only need the lower 32bits.

Comment: The string formatting code you've given isn't valid Java - are you actually writing Java or something else?

Comment: Hi Jon, I am using XTEND but I uses Java's Long class.

Comment: And why are you setting the value to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF when you only actually want 0xFFFFFFFF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
BigInteger in = new BigInteger("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16);        
System.out.println(String.format("%.8s", String.format("%x", in)));
```